# Codeigniter/PHP why result() has to go thru a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Maybe I have some misunderstanding in this part of the Array procedure/syntax...

What I'm wondering is why once I get the result from the db I HAVE to go thru a foreach or other kind of loop.

Let's say I know I'll only get ONE result from the query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("MY QUERY LIMIT 1");
```

Up to now I'll have to go thru it with a loop:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}
```

Is there a way to get the item printed without a loop (for, foreach or other)?
Like:

```
$query->result()->title;

//OR
$query->result()[0]
```

Or something else?

The above method I tried of course are not working...

Perhaps is just a bad practice. Is it impossible? Doable? Or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get only one result, use `row()` instead 
(or `row_array()` if you want it as an array instead of an object)

`row()` returns only the first row in the dataset (no matter how many there are, but usually it's used when you only have one row).

```
$row = $this->db->query("MY QUERY LIMIT 1")->row();
echo $row->title;
echo $row->name;
echo $row->body;
```

as an array:

```
$row = $this->db->query("MY QUERY LIMIT 1")->row_array();
echo $row['title'];
echo $row['name'];
echo $row['body'];
```

Sidenote, you can also return a *specific row* by passing its number:

```
$row = $query->row(5); //works also for its analogue ->row_array(5)
```

For reference, [check the manual here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just try like this

```
$data = $query->result();
echo $data->title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

get result an object

```
$row = $this->db->query("MY QUERY LIMIT 1")->row();
echo $row->title;
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Did you not see the more detailed & similar answer by Damien ?